# Unrecognizable WebApi routing scheme?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I've seen [here](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/webapi/WPNJ120413-How-to-pass-javascript-complex-object-to-ASP.NET-Web-Api-and-MVC.html) that :

*Posted data via ajax  :*

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'api/product',  
 type: 'POST',
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
 data: MyProduct,
 dataType: "json",...
```

*Controller  :*

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
 static readonly IProductRepository repository = new ProductRepository();
 public Product PostProduct(Product item)
 {
  ...
 }
}
```

**Questions:**

1) Looking at `PostProduct(Product item)` is there any convention of `[HttpVerb]Arg(Arg item)` ? 
I mean - which convention from [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) was used ?

2) Looking at `PostProduct(Product item)` how can I know that `item` was successfully populated from the client data ? (what if   there are missing fields ??)

Comment: May I see your `WebApiConfig.cs` file? I guess you configured the routing by `Action Name`. If you did so, the `url` in Ajax should be `api/product/PostProduct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IF** I understood your questions:

1. *any convention of [HttpVerb]Arg(Arg item) `PostProduct(Product item)`*

   - it's the **Post** "prefix" in the action - [Routing and Action Selection](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection):

> **HTTP Methods**. The framework only chooses actions that match the HTTP method of the request, determined as follows:
>
> 1. You can specify the HTTP method with an attribute: AcceptVerbs, HttpDelete, HttpGet, HttpHead, HttpOptions, HttpPatch, HttpPost, or HttpPut.
> 2. Otherwise, **if the name of the controller method starts with** "Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete", "Head", "Options", or "Patch", then by convention the action supports that HTTP method.
> 3. If none of the above, the method supports POST.

2. *how can I know that item was successfully populated from the client data ? (what if there are missing fields ??)*

   - [Model Validation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api)

Taken directly form link:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

 public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Range(0, 999)]
    public double Weight { get; set; }
}
```

Web API Controller

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage PostProduct(Product product)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Do something with the product (not shown).

            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

Client side:

```
//this will fail Model validation because it's missing required "name"
var _data = { "weight": 1, "price": 9.99 };


 $.post("api/product", _data, function (d) {
            ....

 });
```

Hth - if I'm off, apologies....

Comment: ineteresting : i already found the code - (thought he wrote it himself) (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASP-NET-Web-API-Tutorial-c4761894) : no special routing rules.  but look here http://i.stack.imgur.com/zxnaX.jpg

Comment: @RoyiNamir - on [`PProduct`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zxnaX.jpg): IINM, all the other actions match some http request verb (get, put, delete). `PProduct` method would be #3 - _"If none of the above, the method supports POST."_ as well as param matching...